# hibernate one to one using xml mapping with null foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I am new to Hibernate learning entity mapping using hibernate framework via instead of annotation i am using XML for mapping the entities using foreign key.

Here is my database :

[image]

employee.java :

```
    package domaine;
import lombok.*;


@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee { 
      private int employeeId;
      private Account account;
      private String first_name;
      private String last_name;
      private String email;
      
}
```

Account.java :

```
package domaine;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Account {

      private int accountId;

      private Employee employee;

      private String acc_number;
}
```

employee.hbm.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 18 avr. 2017 12:10:58 by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="domaine.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <id name="employeeId" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="first_name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FIRST_NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="last_name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LAST_NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="EMAIL" />
        </property>
        <one-to-one name="account" cascade="all"
            class="domaine.Account"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

account.hbm.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 18 avr. 2017 12:10:58 by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="domaine.Account" table="ACCOUNT">
        <id name="accountId" type="int">
            <column name="IDACCOUNT" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
       
        <property name="acc_number" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ACC_NUMBER" />
        </property>
        
        <one-to-one name="employee"
            class="domaine.Employee"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

test program :

```
package dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import domaine.Account;
import domaine.Employee;


public class TestOneToOne {
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //creating configuration object
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file
        
        //creating session factory object
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        
        //creating session object
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        
        //creating transaction object
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
            
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setAcc_number("123-345-65454");

        // Add new Employee object
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEmail("demo-user@mail.com");
        emp.setFirst_name("demo");
        emp.setLast_name("user");
        
        account.setEmployee(emp);
        emp.setAccount(account);
        
        session.persist(emp);   
        t.commit();//transaction is commited
        session.close();
        
    
        
    }

}
```

The problem is as follow when running the above code: the row in account table is added successfully. The row in employee table is added successfully but **with null value for the foreign key (idaccount)**.

Do you have any idea with the origin of this problem ? and how can i resolve it ?

Thank you